# Divide Dataframe from last 5 months and separate them into 5 different df's from current month?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, date, dataframe

Divide Dataframe from last 5 months and separate them into 5 different df

have a df that has data from past three years. How to divide the df based on last 5months data into 5 different columns and column names being the month names.

df :

```
date      amount

2019-08-23 10
2019-06-23 18
2019-07-21 05
2019-09-09 09
2019-09-19 04
2019-08-27 22
2019-05-03 02
2019-06-27 07
2019-05-25 19
2019-04-27 02
2019-01-19 02
2019-05-28 10
2019-02-22 09
2019-01-25 06
2019-10-22 17
2019-11-02 13
2019-10-29 17
2019-03-11 18
2019-03-11 19
2019-10-19 19
2019-02-17 12
2019-10-21 01
2019-09-01 08
2019-01-15 09
2019-11-15 08
2019-10-10 18
2019-03-31 01
2019-08-17 01
2019-05-27 07
2019-02-24 20
2019-11-03 21
2019-06-28 21
2019-01-06 00
2019-03-30 23
2019-06-27 04
2019-03-08 19
2019-01-30 09
2019-11-15 02
2019-06-04 09
2019-05-03 14
2019-07-01 08
2019-09-20 19
2019-05-15 12
2019-05-17 02
2019-09-21 20
2019-02-14 14
```

Input :

year - 2019
month - 8

Required output

if input is  8  leaving the current month

5 df should be created starting from 7th month to 3rd month

Every time new df should be created .

required df should be :

```
jul_df:



jun_df:


.
.
.
.
march_df:
```

Comment: Can you please give more clarity on your requirements? Why is it 7th month to 3rd month? Do you mean 7th month of the current year to 3rd month of next year?

Comment: And how is input '8' corresponding to 7th or 3rd month?

Comment: if i input 8 , need past 5 months data. so from 7 to 3

Comment: what if I input '6'?

Comment: And should new dataframe be created everytime?? or just append to the existing month's dataframe?

Comment: 8 is the month number

Comment: if input 6 , last 5 months - may to jan,  and new dataframes should be created everytime

Comment: Isn't 'May' 5th month and not 6th?

Comment: leaving the current month,

Comment: Please update the same in the question as well!!

Comment: And if you need each month in separate DF, why do you need columns?

Comment: column names for all are same

Comment: And is input of the year also given? or data of all the years must go to new DF?

Comment: year field is also added in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Setting up the data

First creating the dataframe in a reproducible way:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

# provided data
data = [('2019-08-23', '10'), ('2019-06-23', '18'),('2019-07-21', '05'),
    ('2019-09-09', '09'), ('2019-09-19', '04'), ('2019-08-27', '22'),
    ('2019-05-03', '02'), ('2019-06-27', '07'), ('2019-05-25', '19'),
    ('2019-04-27', '02'), ('2019-01-19', '02'), ('2019-05-28', '10'),
    ('2019-02-22', '09'), ('2019-01-25', '06'), ('2019-10-22', '17'),
    ('2019-11-02', '13'), ('2019-10-29', '17'), ('2019-03-11', '18'),
    ('2019-03-11', '19'), ('2019-10-19', '19'), ('2019-02-17', '12'),
    ('2019-10-21', '01'), ('2019-09-01', '08'), ('2019-01-15', '09'),
    ('2019-11-15', '08'), ('2019-10-10', '18'), ('2019-03-31', '01'),
    ('2019-08-17', '01'), ('2019-05-27', '07'), ('2019-02-24', '20'),
    ('2019-11-03', '21'), ('2019-06-28', '21'), ('2019-01-06', '00'),
    ('2019-03-30', '23'), ('2019-06-27', '04'), ('2019-03-08', '19'),
    ('2019-01-30', '09'), ('2019-11-15', '02'), ('2019-06-04', '09'),
    ('2019-05-03', '14'), ('2019-07-01', '08'), ('2019-09-20', '19'),
    ('2019-05-15', '12'), ('2019-05-17', '02'), ('2019-09-21', '20'),
    ('2019-02-14', '14')]

# create df
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=('date', 'amount'))
```

It looks like you're working with `object` datatypes - this operation will be far easier with proper data types:

```
# convert dtypes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
df['amount'] = df['amount'].astype('int')
```

To visualize what we're looking at, I sorted the data to make it easier to assess results

```
df = df.sort_values(['date', 'amount']).reset_index(drop=True)
df.head()
```

```
    date    amount
0   2019-01-06  0
1   2019-01-15  9
2   2019-01-19  2
3   2019-01-25  6
4   2019-01-30  9
```

## Getting back the data

### Recommendation

Getting a set/list/dictionary of dataframes will might become a bit confusing, so you mmight want to think about if that's a true requirement.  If not, you can just filter ad-hoc from your single dataframe by accessing `df['date'].dt` to slice in a number of ways:

```
# getting things in a certain month
mar_df = df[df['date'].dt.month == 3]  # only filtered on month
mar_df = df[(df['date'].dt.month == 3) & (df['date'].dt.year == 2019)]  # month & year

# getting values in a range of months
mar_jul_df = df[df['date'].dt.month.between(3, 7)]
mar_jul_df = df[(df['date'].dt.year == 2019) & (df['date'].dt.month.between(3, 7))]

# getting values between two dates
mar_jul_df = df[(df['date'] >= dt.datetime(2019, 3, 1)) & (df['date'] <= dt.datetime(2019, 7, 31))]
```

Doing this you'll be able to collect filtered data frames as you need them with more control and likely readability.  This doesn't account for situations where your required data could, for instance, start in December 2018 and end in April 2019.

#### Using [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

Getting a range of dates allows us to get the upper and lower limits that we're looking for, or the range of dates within at a specified frequency, makes this more flexible.

```
# getting upper and lower bounds
>>> start_stop_date = pd.date_range(end=dt.datetime(2019, 8, 1), freq='5MS', periods=2)
>>> start_stop_date
DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-01', '2019-08-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='5MS')
```

Using this, we can filter values using this list

```
# setting two conditions -- on or after start & before end
mar_jul_df = df[(df['date'] >= start_stop_date[0]) & (df['date'] < start_stop_date[1])]
# modifying boundaries to exclude 2019-08-01
start_stop_date[1] = start_stop_date[1] - dt.timedelta(days=1)
mar_jul_df = df[df['date'].between(start_stop_date[0], start_stop_date[1])]
```

### Set of dataframes

#### Simplest case

If your solution requires returning five separate dataframes, the simplest solution might be using a list comprehension for the months of interest *if your data range will always fall in the same year*:

```
# list comprehension
df_list = [df[df['date'].dt.month == mo] for mo in range(3, 8)]

# returning individual dfs
mar_df, apr_df, may_df, jun_df, jul_df = iter(df_list)
```

#### Realistic case

Outside of this simple case, you'll need to use `pd.date_range`.

```
# getting range of dates
>>> boundary_dates = pd.date_range(end=dt.datetime(2019, 8, 1), freq='MS', periods=6)
>>> boundary_dates
DatetimeIndex(['2019-03-01', '2019-04-01', '2019-05-01', '2019-06-01', '2019-07-01', '2019-08-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='MS')
```

This gives you a range of six dates to come up with 5 sets of boundaries.  You can create a list of boundaries using `zip`:

```
>>> [[l_bound, u_bound] for l_bound, u_bound in zip(boundary_dates, boundary_dates[1:])]
[[Timestamp('2019-03-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')],
 [Timestamp('2019-04-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')],
 [Timestamp('2019-05-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')],
 [Timestamp('2019-06-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2019-07-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')],
 [Timestamp('2019-07-01 00:00:00', freq='MS'), Timestamp('2019-08-01 00:00:00', freq='MS')]]
```

To take advantage of `pd.Series.between`, subtract `dt.timedelta(days=1)` again.

```
boundaries = [[l_bound, u_bound - dt.timedelta(days=1)] for
    l_bound, u_bound in zip(boundary_dates, boundary_dates[1:])]

df_list = [df[df['date'].between(b) for b in boundaries]
mar_df, apr_df, may_df, jun_df, jul_df = iter(df_list)
```

Since you call for something dynamic, you aren't going to want to specify names for each dataframe every time.  Returning this as a dictionary allows assigning the dataframe to a key (from `dt.datetime.strftime` so that it can be pulled out more easily:

```
df_dict = {b[0].strftime('%b_%y_df'): 
        {df[df['date'].between(b[0], b[1])] for b in boundaries}
```

You can still easily access the individual dataframes with `df_dict.values()` since each value contains one dataframe.

#### Creating a function

To wrap these steps up in a function that gives you flexibility on the year and month you're looking at, as well as the number of months you're looking to return:

```
def monthly_dfs(df, year, month, n=5):
    """return a number of dataframes for the n months preceding a given month"""
    # generate list of boundaries for months of interest
    before_dt = dt.datetime(year, month, 1)
    boundary_dates = pd.date_range(end=before_dt, freq='MS', periods=n+1)
    # get boundary pairs
    boundaries = [[l_bound, u_bound - dt.timedelta(days=1)] for 
        l_bound, u_bound in zip(boundary_dates, boundary_dates[1:])]
    # return df within each boundary pair with key according to month start
    return {b[0].strftime('%b_%y_df'): 
        df[df['date'].between(b[0], b[1])] for b in boundaries}
```

```
df_dict = monthly_dfs(df, 2019, 8)
mar_df, apr_df, may_df, jun_df, jul_df = df_dict.values()
```

#### Output

Reformatted a bit, here's `df_dict`:

```
{
    'Mar_19_df':
           date        amount
        9  2019-03-08      19
        10 2019-03-11      18
        11 2019-03-11      19
        12 2019-03-30      23
        13 2019-03-31       1,
    'Apr_19_df':
           date        amount
        14 2019-04-27       2,
    'May_19_df':
           date        amount
        15 2019-05-03       2
        16 2019-05-03      14
        17 2019-05-15      12
        18 2019-05-17       2
        19 2019-05-25      19
        20 2019-05-27       7
        21 2019-05-28      10,
    'Jun_19_df':
           date        amount
        22 2019-06-04       9
        23 2019-06-23      18
        24 2019-06-27       4
        25 2019-06-27       7
        26 2019-06-28      21,
    'Jul_19_df':
           date        amount
        27 2019-07-01       8
        28 2019-07-21       5
}
```

These can be accessed using the keys created, for example:

```
>>>df_dict['Mar_19_df']
    date    amount
9   2019-03-08  19
10  2019-03-11  18
11  2019-03-11  19
12  2019-03-30  23
13  2019-03-31  1
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to first list the months and year, as a month 3 of 2019, can have months 1,2 of 2019 and 10,11,12 of 2018. Then work based on string matching for months.

```
year = 2019
month = 3
month_list=[]
year_list=[]
for i in range(5):
    if month-i-2<0:
        month_list.append((month-i-2)%12)
        year_list.append(year-1)
    else:
         month_list.append((month-i-2))
         year_list.append(year)

month_list =  ["%02d" % (x+1) for x in month_list]
month_names = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']
print(month_list)
dataframe_collection = {}

for i in range(5):
    ## filtering year
    df_temp = df[df['date'].str.contains(str(year_list[i]))]
    ## filtering month
    df_temp = df[df['date'].str.contains(str('-'+month_list[i]+'-'))]

    dataframe_collection[month_names[int(month_list[i])-1]]=df_temp

for i in dataframe_collection:
    print(i)
    print(dataframe_collection[i])
```

Comment: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: can you please tell which line?

Comment: Also, verify that  you don't have any `NaN`s in your dataFrame

Answer (score 1):

You did not post your code so the only thing i can give you is a direction:

fetch your table as a pandas df_dbtable, join the two dfs on column 0 creating a new df_new with columns `0.sqltable | 1.df`. Truncate the sql table and insert the new df.

Have fun exploring.

Comment: don't mix up sql with python. Import the database table in python as a dataframe. There, perform all operations using python. Then store the new dataframe in your table back in the database